# my SSL site shows lock icon in Chrome, but shows warning sign in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl

My SSL secure site (goinspire.com/secure-payment) shows a lock symbol in Chrome, but in Firefox it shows a warning sign instead. According to http://www.whynopadlock.com there is an http url there that's a problem. However, in my php file I changed it to https, so I can't understand why it should still be a problem.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

UPDATE: The lock icon shows in IE as well, so I guess Firefox is the problem. I'm using the newest version of Firefox and Chrome. This is the error I am seeing:

[image]

Update: Thanks for all your help! Commenting out this line fixed it!

```
<script src="https://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firefox and Chrome use two different certificate stores.  Please provide more information about the certificate itself.  What is the cause of the "warning sign" in Firefox for instance.  My guess the certificant wasn't signed by a CA that Firefox trusts.

Comment: The certificate is from godaddy. I believe the warning sign in FF is from this URL:  http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js, but in my php files i changed it to https so I don't know why it should be an issue.

Comment: You can't just serve github.io content over a https if github.io doesn't agree it would be a secure connection. The domain malsup.github.io would have to be configured to support a secure connection it likely doesn't if its just serving javascript. Did the website work in Firefox ever?  Test with IE and update the question.  Also include which versions of Firefox and Chrome your using.

Comment: IE works too. The website worked all along in FF, and still does, it's just the warning icon that's the problem.

Comment: So how can I serve the github content over https?

Comment: On that specific content, I don't believe you can, so transfer the content to your server if want to prevent the warning message from being displayed.  **But I still maintain the certificate itself is the problem.**

Comment: The certificate is from godaddy. Could it be a problem from their end?

Comment: @r3515 - GoDaddy just signed the certificate.  Your configuration could be to blame. A screenshot of the warning might be helpful.

Comment: question updated with screenshot

Comment: You have two problems.  The first your serving mixed content.  The second there is something wrong with your certificate hence that "does not serve identity information"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is linking to http://www.popu.ps/... and http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js Could you temporarily remove these scripts and check again?

In the `jquery` case the best practice is putting the scrip in your server and linking within the same domain.

Comment: It's okay in Chrome by me too. Only Firefox shows the warning sign, and that's the case on multiple computers.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I edited the answer with an alternative. Check it, please.

Comment: Thanks! I commented out that line, and it's still an issue. Thanks

Comment: You still have mixed/cross referenced scripts. Check again.

Comment: I don't see it in the page source - where do you see it?

Comment: It seems some Wordpress plugin is including it. Turn off plugins temporarily and try again.

Comment: I don't think it's a plugin... can you tell me where you see it so I can try to find where it's coming from? In Firefox's "Page Source" I don't see it.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-I to open Firefox console and reload the page. You will wee all scripts being downloaded.

Comment: Okay I only see the github one, not the malsup one. I disabled all WP plugins but I still see the warning. And it's funny - because I commented out that line from my php file! (header.php)

Comment: I see it right now! No warnings. Clear your Firefox cache.

Comment: Oohh you're right! Now I just have to find out what that line of code did and if it's important...

Comment: In general, you have to host your scripts. Remove anything that is not worth having, because they slow down your page too.